# Google Maps Api Version 3 Auto-Zoom

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I have a Problem i am a beginner in Google Maps and not really good in Java Script but in PHP. Is there a possibel Solution for an "Auto-Zoom" Function. I have different Markers on my Map an i want to Zoom automaticcaly to the level that every Marker is Visibel ?

Is there any Solution Please Help me !

Ok This is my Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCxuRdCmN2BO5PD7kwI0mO8JflcUOF4CtI&sensor=true">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.903033, 10.496063),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
        var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var contentString;
        <? php
        $i = 1;
        foreach($FertigID as $ID) {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Daten_CH WHERE ID = ".$ID."");
            while ($Ergebnisse = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // Werden alle ergebnisse (ID´s) in einen Array geschriebenn 
                if (isset($Ergebnisse["GIS_y"]) && $Ergebnisse["GIS_y"] != "" && $Ergebnisse["GIS_y"] != " ") { ?> contentString = '<a href="Change.php?ID=<?php echo $ID; ?>"><input type="button" value="BEARBEITEN"></button></a>';
    var Position = new google.maps.LatLng( <? php echo $Ergebnisse["GIS_y"]; ?> , <? php echo $Ergebnisse["GIS_x"]; ?> );
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString
                    });
                    var marker <? php echo $i; ?> = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: Position,
                        map: map,
                        title: '<?php echo $Ergebnisse["AA_Objektname"]; ?>'
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker <? php echo $i; ?> , 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker <? php echo $i; ?> );
                    });
                    <? php
                }
            }

            $i++;

        } ?>
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Where i have to change to get a solution because i get the points out of an Database

Comment: my markers have the Name "Marker1,Marker2..." What should this do "foreach(marker in markers)" I think there should be my Marker Names ?

Comment: I have no idea what i have to do sorry ! I just want to add some Markes out of an Database in an Map ? Can you please write a little bit code for me ! Iam just not an Professional like you -.-

Answer (score 9):

What you want to do, is create a [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds) object, use its `extend` method to extend the bounds with your markers (using [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) objects), then use the `fitBounds` (or `panToBounds` if you want animation) of the [Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map) object and the map will auto zoom to a position where it will show all your markers.

Here's some basic pseudocode:

```
// You create your map. You have to do this anyway :)
// The Map object has a lot of options, you specify them according to your needs.
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    'param1': 'value1',
    'param2': 'value2'
});

// Create a new LatLngBounds object
var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// Add your points to the LatLngBounds object.
foreach(marker in markers) {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lng);
    markerBounds.extend(point);
}

// Then you just call the fitBounds method and the Maps widget does all rest.
map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
```

Here's your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCxuRdCmN2BO5PD7kwI0mO8JflcUOF4CtI&sensor=true">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.903033, 10.496063),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);

        var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var contentString;
        <? php
        $i = 1;
        foreach($FertigID as $ID) {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Daten_CH WHERE ID = ".$ID."");
            while ($Ergebnisse = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // Werden alle ergebnisse (ID´s) in einen Array geschriebenn 
                if (isset($Ergebnisse["GIS_y"]) && $Ergebnisse["GIS_y"] != "" && $Ergebnisse["GIS_y"] != " ") { ?> contentString = '<a href="Change.php?ID=<?php echo $ID; ?>"><input type="button" value="BEARBEITEN"></button></a>';
    var Position = new google.maps.LatLng( <? php echo $Ergebnisse["GIS_y"]; ?> , <? php echo $Ergebnisse["GIS_x"]; ?> );
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString
                    });
                    var marker <? php echo $i; ?> = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: Position,
                        map: map,
                        title: '<?php echo $Ergebnisse["AA_Objektname"]; ?>'
                    });

                    markerBounds.extend(Position); // you call this method for each Position (LatLng object)

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker <? php echo $i; ?> , 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker <? php echo $i; ?> );
                    });
                    <? php
                }
            }

            $i++;

        } ?>
        map.fitBounds(markerBounds); // Then you call this method here.
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi. If this solved your problem, please mark this post as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Where can I do this ?

Comment: There must be a button or something which says 'accept as correct answer'. I'm not sure exactly what the button says.